# Add HTML Dynamically on Drag N Drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

A simple way to drag and drop html elements or content on a web page?

1. The goal is to drag the element and drop it on a container.
2. Once the element is dropped it will dynamically add html content based on its id.

Answer (score 0):

To begin you will need to create an html page with the following code.

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Drag N Drop Elements</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- The element to be dragged and dropped -->
        <span class="elements" id="paragraph">|Paragraph|</span>

        <!-- The target for the dragged elements -->
        <div id="document-section">This is the target for the drag n drop.</div>


        <!--import javascript-->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>        
        <script src="dragndrop.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The following html in the example above is the element that you will be able to drag once completing all the javascript is added later on.

```
<span class="elements" id="paragraph">|Paragraph|</span>
```

**Note:** You can add other draggable elements by giving them the class elements and assigning a different id.

The next important element to discuss is the area on the page where the draggable elements are going to be dropped. To allow elements to be dropped in this area I have assigned it the id of #document-section that you will see used in the javascipt example later on.

**Note:** You don't have to use text in the  div element below but make sure it has some width, height, and a border so that the user can see where to drop the element.

```
<div id="document-section">This is the target for the drag n drop.</div>
```

Next you will need to create a javascript file named dragndrop.js and place it in the same folder as the html file you created in the first step.

Javascript:

```
                //store the id of the item being dragged
                var dragging;         

                /*make all of the elements draggable*/
                $(".elements").draggable({helper:"clone"});

                 /*on dragstart event for .elements*/  
                $(".elements").on("dragstart",function(){

                    //get the id of the element being dragged
                    dragging = $(this).attr("id");


                });//end on dragstart event for .elements


         //fire event when an element is dropped on #document-section div  
          $("#document-section").droppable({//begin droppable event

       drop: function(event,ui) {//begin drop function




             //switch case statement used to detect what element has been dropped
             switch(dragging){//begin switch case


                  case "paragraph":   


                  //array to hold the paragraph
                  var paragraph = [];



    //if dragging variable equals "paragraph"
    if(dragging === "paragraph"){//begin if then


      //add the paragraph
      paragraph.push('<p>Hello, I am a paragraph</p>');

    //append the paragraph to your container I used #document-section in this example
   $("#document-section").append(paragraph.join(""));

    //set dragging to null to prevent duplicate elements being creating on drop
    dragging = null;

                 break;               


             }//end switch case  


             }//end if then    


      }//end drop function
    });//end droppable event
```

Once finished you should be able to drag the "paragraph" text on to the "This is the target for the drag n drop.", and see the results.